# Not able to add product custom data to cart after updating to woocommerce 3.0 +

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add custom variations with the product in cart but after a couples of struggling got to add product to cart but with no variation data.

here is the code i am using:
javascript:

```
 //create request object
      cartItemobj.productID = jQuery('#product_id').val();
      cartItemobj.qty = qtys;
      cartItemobj.customData = jQuery('.wct_frontend_design_right_panel').html();
      cartItemobj.designAttr = designData;
      cartItemobj.measurementsAttr = measurementsData;

      jQuery.ajax ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:  jQuery('#admin-ajax').val(),
                    data: {action:'wct_add_to_cart',wct_design_data:cartItemobj},
                    success: function( data )
                    {
                      if( data == 'cart_updated' )
                      {
                        jQuery('.wct_add_to_cart_loader').hide();
                        window.location.href = jQuery('#wct_cart_url').val();
                      }
                    },
                    error: function(){}
      });
```

This Javascript is calling this function which perform add to cart operation

```
function wct_add_to_cart()
{
   global $wpdb,$woocommerce;
   $final_product_id = '';
   $final_custom_variations_id = '';
   $uIds = uniqid().rand(0,10);
   $guid = get_permalink($_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['productID']);
   $post_data=array(
                'post_author'=>1,
                'post_status'=>'publish',
                'post_name'=>'product-'.$_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['productID'].'-variation',
                'post_parent'=>$_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['productID'],
                'post_title'=>'wct_custom_variation',
                'post_type'=>'product_variation',
                'guid' => $guid ,
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'ping_status' => 'closed',
                'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'post_date_gmt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'post_modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'post_modified_gmt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
);
//$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data, true);
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix."posts", $post_data );
$post_ids = $wpdb->insert_id;
$final_product_id = $_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['productID'];
$price = $wpdb->get_var("select meta_value from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key = '_india-1_price' and post_id = $final_product_id");
update_post_meta( $post_ids, '_india-1_price', $price);
update_post_meta( $post_ids, 'attribute_scwct-variation', 'scwct-variation' );

$final_custom_variations_id = $post_ids;
$get_price = get_post_meta($post_ids,'_india-1_price',TRUE);

$arr = array();
$arr['type'] = 'custom';
$arr['design'] = 'custom-data_' . $uIds;
$arr['wct_custom_price'] = $price;

if( isset($_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['measurementsAttr']) && $_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['measurementsAttr']['torso_length'] )
{
$measurement = 'Torso Length: '.$_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['measurementsAttr']['torso_length'].', Sleeves Length: '.$_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['measurementsAttr']['sleeves_length'].', Shoulder Width: '.$_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['measurementsAttr']['shoulder_width'].', Neck: '.$_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['measurementsAttr']['neck'].', Chest Around: '.$_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['measurementsAttr']['chest_around'].', Stomach Area: '.$_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['measurementsAttr']['stomach_area'].', Hips Area: '.$_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['measurementsAttr']['hips_area'].', Bicep Around: '.$_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['measurementsAttr']['bicep_around'];

$arr['Measurements'] = $measurement;
}

if($woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $final_product_id, $_REQUEST['wct_design_data']['qty'], $final_custom_variations_id, arr, null ) )
{
  echo 'cart_updated';
}
```

This code is adding product to cart but not refreshing the page. Cart is updated once you manually reload the page but without custom variations.
Please Help